# Calculate $f^{(n)}(0)$ where $f(x) = e^{x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

The problem is stated as:

> Calculate $f^{(n)}(0)$ where $f(x) = e^{x^2}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$

**Attempt:**

We know that $e^{x} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}x^k +\frac{x^{n+1}e^{\theta x}}{(n+1)!}$ for some $\theta = \theta (x) \in (0,1)$

Hence, $e^{x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}x^{2k} +\frac{x^{2n+1}e^{\theta x^2}}{(n+1)!}$

Comparing terms with the general Maclaurin polynomial, we get that:

$\frac{1}{k!}x^{2k} = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^{n}$

First, we have to equate the exponent of the $x$ - terms, so $2k = n \iff k = n/2$

Therefore, we have that:

$\Rightarrow f^{n}(0) = \frac{n!}{(n/2)!}$

However, since we had natural numbers in our expression, I wonder what would happen if $n$ was odd in this case. How could I generalize this even further?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

\begin{align*}
e^{x^2}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(x^2)^k}{k!}\\
&=\frac{x^0}{0!}+\frac{x^2}{1!}+\frac{x^4}{2!}+\frac{x^6}{3!}+\dots\\
&=\frac{x^0}{0!}+0\frac{x^1}{1!}+2!\frac{x^2}{2!}+0\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{4!}{2!}\frac{x^4}{4!}+0\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{6!}{3!}\frac{x^6}{6!}+\dots\\
\end{align*}

So,

$$e^{x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\frac{x^k}{k!},$$

where

\begin{align*}
a_k=\begin{cases}
\frac{k!}{(k/2)!}&\text{if $k$ is even}\\
0&\text{if $k$ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is odd, then since $f^{(n)}$ is an odd function, $f^{(n)}(0)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the problem more general and compute the $n^{th}$ derivative at any value of $n$.

They all write
$$f^{(n)}(x)=e^{x^2} P_n(x)$$ Computing the first ones (using the chain rule makes it easy)
$$f^{(n+1)}(x)=e^{x^2}\left(2x P_n(x)+P'_n(x) \right)$$

So, you have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n(x) \\
 1 & 2 x \\
 2 & 4 x^2+2 \\
 3 & 8 x^3+12 x \\
 4 & 16 x^4+48 x^2+12 \\
 5 & 32 x^5+160 x^3+120 x \\
 6 & 64 x^6+480 x^4+720 x^2+120 \\
 7 & 128 x^7+1344 x^5+3360 x^3+1680 x \\
 8 & 256 x^8+3584 x^6+13440 x^4+13440 x^2+1680 \\
 9 & 512 x^9+9216 x^7+48384 x^5+80640 x^3+30240 x \\
 10 & 1024 x^{10}+23040 x^8+161280 x^6+403200 x^4+302400 x^2+30240
\end{array}
\right)$$ where you can notice interesting patterns.

In fact
$$\color{red}{P_n=i^{-n} H_n(i x)\implies f^{(n)}(x)=i^{-n} H_n(i x)e^{x^2}}$$

Now, if you make $x=0$, as expected since $e^{x^2}$ is a even function, $f^{(2n+1)}(0)=0$ and for $f^{(2n)}(0)$ generates the  sequence
$$\{2,12,120,1680,30240,665280,\cdots\}$$ which is your result.

Comment: Did you calculate these $P_n(x)$  for different values of n or is there any computation you used? if any, let us know

Comment: @polymath It looks like they used the recursive formula they stated.

Comment: @Milten Thanks, I just overlooked and wondered if it's Legendre's polynomial 

Comment: @Polymath. They are Hermite polynomials. I added to my answer

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, thanks it's a great help for people like me with little maths backround.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you. That's really interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

Comparing terms exactly the same way you did for the even order terms, the odd order derivatives are zero at the origin, as the coefficients of the odd degree terms of the Maclaurin series are all zero.

Comment: They have to be zero, so the correct expression would be $n!/(n/2)!$ for even n's, and 0 for odd n's?